# Pairing two HC05 modules using arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I want to send integer values from 1 arduino (nano) to to another arduino (mega2560).
arduino nano have accelerometer connected which continuously give integer values to it. I want to send it to arduno mega2560.
I have tried many tutorials but I cant pair them.
Also guide me about the pin 34, key pin etc matter. I dnt know how they are used.
I have two HC05 bluetooth modules. having 6 pins, one State and EN. 
Please guide me through step by step how to automatically pair them when they power on.
its in my FINAL YEAR PROJECT so please help.

Answer (score 0):

For more easy fork you need:
1. Two serial->USB converters
2. Two modules HC-05.
3. PC/Laptop

You need configure one module as master, another - as slave. And then pairing them. For this purpose better use modules connected to PC over USB->serial converter and terminal (TeraTerm, Putty, etc) for both modules.

Good and sufficient guides:

- https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/bluetooth-hc05-how-to-pair-two-modules/
- http://elasticsheep.com/2011/05/serial-bluetooth-module-masterslave-connection/